# hide element when another element is focused

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can i hide the element with the classname "button", when the search-textfield is focused, with only css?

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <form action="/search" method="get">
    <label class="button searchbutton" for="searchleft">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
          class="search-icon icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-search" width="44" height="44"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#2c3e50" fill="none" 
          stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" />
        <line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" />
      </svg>
    </label>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, class: 'search' , id: 'searchleft' , type: 'search' , placeholder: t('search') %>
  </form>
</div>
```

i tried doing this, but without luck:

```css
.search:focus .search-container .searchbutton {
  display: none !important;
  }
```

Comment: [why complicate your question by not showing the generated HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Because your label is linked to the input with the `for` attribute you can use the `:focus-within` pseudo class as per the code below.

Note that your button will also disappear on click, this is because clicking on the label also gives the input box focus due to the `for` attribute:

```css
.search-container:focus-within .button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <form action="/search" method="get">
    <label class="button searchbutton" for="searchleft">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="search-icon icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-search" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#2c3e50" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" />
        <line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" />
      </svg>
    </label>
    <input class='search' id='searchleft' placeholder='search'>
  </form>
</div>
```

If they were not linked then you can use the `[:has()][1]` pseudo class as follows (but note this doesn't work on all browsers yet, e.g firefox):

```css
.search-container:has(input:focus) .button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <form action="/search" method="get">
    <label class="button searchbutton">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="search-icon icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-search" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#2c3e50" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" />
        <line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" />
      </svg>
    </label>
    <input class='search' id='searchleft' placeholder='search'>
  </form>
</div>
```